# How to get request_token using OAuth with twitter

Tags: twitter, oauth

I am using the following method URI to request token from twitter.

Note: here new lines are just for display purpose only.

```
http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token?
oauth_consumer_key=9cS99b2406CUpATOeggeA&
oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&
oauth_signature=3e18bafc4c4fd6b23f988bcd1a8c0ab2d65db784
oauth_timestamp=1267523137&
oauth_nonce=56e66e9f8bd28b320f86a16407f9911d&
oauth_version=1.0&
oauth_callback=http://playground.com
```

But it gives error "Failed to validate oauth signature and token".

The base string I used to computer *signature* is as bellow:

```
GET&
http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&
oauth_consumer_key%3D9cS99b2406CUpATOeggeA%26
oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26
oauth_timestamp%3D1267523137%26
oauth_nonce%3D56e66e9f8bd28b320f86a16407f9911d%26
oauth_version%3D1.0%26
oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fplayground.com
```

Please correct me where am I making mistake.

Comment: if you done with twitter signin please provide me your working example on somewhere like github or plunker

Comment: I am not able to get the signature order working. If you figured that part out can you please update the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is with the order of the parameters.  The parameters for the base string need to be in order.  If they are out of order, it will give you that error.

So your base string should be this...

```
GET&
http%3A%2F%2Ftwitter.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&
oauth_consumer_key%3D9cS99b2406CUpATOeggeA%26
oauth_nonce%3D56e66e9f8bd28b320f86a16407f9911d%26
oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26
oauth_timestamp%3D1267523137%26
oauth_version%3D1.0%26
oauth_callback%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fplayground.com
```

Notice that your "nonce" was not in the correct spot.

Also, normally, the "signature" parameter is appended to the end of the request URL.

http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#anchor46

Appendix A.5.1

Comment: I am still getting the same error 'Failed to validate oauth signature and token'

Comment: I believe the `oauth_callback` parameter should also be in the correct order.  Also, when I mean correct order, these need to be in order when creating the signature.  If you are still having an issue, edit your post and add your NEW base string so we can see what it is.

Comment: hi.. may i know, how can i get oauth_signature?.. thanks

Comment: Hi, is there any working example code for twitter login ? i am not getting what would be the URL for getting `access_token`

Answer (score 0):

What Eclipsed4utoo said - though if you're still getting the error you should check that you've registered your application as being browser based (and specified a callback) in the Twitter dev admin pages.

If it's listed as a desktop app but you include &oauth_callback in calls you'll see the signature validation error you mention.